# Do >iOS8 devices randomize Bluetooth-MAC address

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, wifi, bluetooth

iOS8 has brought the randomization of the WiFi MAC-address. My question is if the Bluetooth MAC-address is also randomized in the same manner on iDevices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not on iOS 9.1 and earlier. Also, the wifi isn't always "randomized"

Answer (score 2):

The answer right now on my iPhone 7 with iOS 10 is yes. On iOS 9.1 and earlier this wasn't the case.

I've been doing bluetooth scans today while toggling Airplane mode on and off. Every time I toggle Airplane mode off a new device, with a brand new MAC address, appears in the list.